# nosetests coverage including Python packages

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose, coverage.py, python-coverage

I'm using nosetests to run a few unit tests and show me our code coverage using something like:

```
nosetests -w ./test --with-xunit --with-coverage --cover-tests
```

This works well except for the fact that I'm seeing a bunch of Python packages in the output. Here's a sample:

```
ctypes._endian                 34     12    35%   15-20, 24-32, 50-60
ctypes.macholib                 1      1   100%   
email                          29     25    86%   56-57, 65-66
email.errors                   15     14    93%   39
```

How do I exclude these packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the `nosetests --cover-package=<name>` option. It will restrict coverage output to the listed packages/modules. You can use it more than once if your tests cover multiple packages.

Comment: Note, you can use the `--cover-package=<name>` switch multiple times if you want more than one package.

Comment: I've spent 15 minutes wondering why I only got one (the last) listed cover-package using a config file, but stupidly I had multiple invocations of `cover-package=foo \n cover-package=bar`.

I'm a dumbass but hopefully someone else sees this!

Comment: In order to specify multiple packages, one needs to separate them with commas like `--cover-package=first.package,another.package`. This is somehow not explicitly described even in [the nosetests docs](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=nose_cover_package), but I leared it from the *example* here: https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=nose_cover_package . Using the parameter multiple times apparently leads to only the last one considered.